# using "ontouchstart" or "onclick" depending on device for custom audio dial

Tags: javascript, html, css

I've create a website whereby users can use various audio dials to create their own unique audio sound (ie a mix of rain, crackling fire etc). My site is linked below:

http://immerseinnature.com/

I'm unable to get the audio to work on mobile / touch screen devices. I think this is stemming from my use of onclick="play()" in the html input tag. When i replace onclick with ontouchstart, the audio dial works on touch screen devices, but not on desktop.

Does anyone know if there is a way i could get onclick and ontouchstart to work simultaneously?

thanks

HMTL

```
  <li>             
                    <div class="audio_buttons">
                        <img src="images/fire.png" class="audio-icons " id="fire-icon">
                        <input type="range" oninput="setVolume(this)" id='volume1' min=0 max=1 step=0.01 value='0' onclick="play()">
                        <audio loop id="cs_audio" controls style="display:none">

                        <source src="audio/fire_loop.mp3" type="audio/mp3">
                        </audio>
                    </div>
            </li>
```

JS

```
var audio_file_1;
var volume1;

        function init()  {
        audio_file_1 = document.getElementById("cs_audio");
         volume1 = document.getElementById("volume1");
         audio_file_1.play();
        }

        function setVolume() {
        var audio_file_1  = document.getElementById("cs_audio");
        audio_file_1.volume = document.getElementById("volume1").value;

        }


        function play() {
        var audio = document.getElementById("cs_audio");
        audio.play();
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
const event = "ontouchstart" in window ? "touchstart" : "onclick";
document.getElementById("volume1").addEventListener(event, () => play());
```

In JavaScript `ontouchstart` will be in the window object when using a touch screen device, using this you can listen for the right event.